# I am not able to refresh the old view on button click

Tags: iphone

I have viewBased Application, i have 3 view controller in that.
When I want to go back to first view from second view,  I want that view to be reloaded from start.
Code I use to dismiss the present view is:

```
//Back Button Code:   

[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    

//Code I use to go to new view is:   

[self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

Comment: It is a "View-Based Application", not "viewBased Application". You don't have to use camel-caps when speaking plain English. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting what you trying to do...
put your logic inside viewWillAppear method... which gets called everytime view Loads..

Comment: I have nothing in viewWillAppear..I have all my logic in button press function.

Comment: Okk.. so when you click on the button you want to load the same view from start ??

Comment: Yea. Suppose I have textfield and I want it to be blank again at the start

Answer (score 0):

> When I want to go back to first view from second view, I want **that** view to be reloaded from start.

Wich one?

---

Well I think it should work since dismissing a modal dialog unloads it. What happens exactly that you don't want? You must have retained something you don't want to.

Comment: First View I want to load from start when I am going back from second view..I added the code also.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear if you want your first view to restart, or your second view to restart.

Answer for both cases:

If you want view 1 to restart, move the code you need re-executed into viewWillAppear()

If you want view 2 to restart, it's been released from memory so going back to it will call viewDidLoad() and restart it anyway.

Hope that helps....